# Avoid losing data when installing Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04

If I install Ubuntu on top of Windows 8.1, will it overwrite OS disk or entire hard-disk? Because I have so much data on my laptop.

Comment: Did you even google even ones before asking question here.

Answer (score 1):

When you install Ubuntu, using a bootable USB with Ubuntu on it. You will have different choices. Choose install ubuntu alongside Windows. Be sure you have enough room for Ubuntu. Nevertheless, you better should take a backup of your files, just to be sure. There can always go something wrong, like GRUB being missinstalled or boot-problems etc. I have done it multiple times without problems. But the first time is allways a bit tricky.

**But in theory it should be possible.**

Answer (score 0):

If you choose "Replace Windows with Ubuntu" during the installation, the entire hard disk will be overwritten. Transfer your data on Windows to another disk before doing this.

However, I would certainly recommend installing Ubuntu alongside Windows instead. This way, you'll still be able to run Windows applications and you can easily go back to using Windows if you don't like Ubuntu. Later, if you decide, you can delete Windows and run Ubuntu only.

Answer (score 0):

for installing ubuntu after windows ,its better to choose "Something else" item and then install ubuntu in one of the partition of you disk that is empty.
for that you can use this link:
[How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Please don't just post links: instead, include the essential parts of the article you are referencing.  Links break.